# Querying If the same user has not have two different entry ORACLE sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle18c

I want to get a query that If the same user has only 1 entry on the database.

I have two different tables `s` and `r`. `s` have `Name, Gender, ID`. `r` have `Code, rID, Numb`.

The user can have an entry with `Numb` attribute with two different values `20` and `21`. I am trying to retrieve only if
the user has `r.Numb = 21` not `20` together. Also, I used this query but it was not successful. How can solve it?

```
SELECT s.Name, s.Gender
FROM s, r
WHERE s.ID = r.rID
    AND r.Code = '21'
    AND NOT r.Numb = '20'
GROUP BY s.Name, s.Gender
HAVING COUNT(s.Name) = 1
```

I searched on the StackOverflow but I could not get the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Building on your existing query with aggregation, you can conditional sums in the `HAVING` clause that filter on users that have `r.Numb = 21` and not `r.Numb = 20`:

```
SELECT s.Name, s.Gender
FROM s
INNER JOIN r ON s.ID = r.rID
GROUP BY s.Name, s.Gender
HAVING 
    SUM(CASE WHEN r.Numb = 21 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
    AND SUM(CASE WHEN r.Numb = 2O THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Or you can use `EXISTS` and `NOT EXITS`:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM s
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM r WHERE r.rID = s.ID AND r.Numb = 21)
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM r WHERE r.rID = s.ID AND r.Numb = 20)
```

Important note: always use *explicit, standard joins*. Implicit joins (with commas in the where clause) have been discouraged for more than 20 years.

Comment: I tried both of them but it did not return any result

Comment: I removed this part ` AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM r WHERE r.rID = s.ID AND r.Numb = 20)` and its worked

Answer (score 0):

You can alter your query little bit to get the desired output (apart from `EXISTS` solution)

```
SELECT s.Name, 
       s.Gender 
  FROM s join r 
    ON s.ID = r.rID
 WHERE r.Numb in ('20','21')
GROUP BY s.Name, s.Gender 
HAVING SUM(case when r.numb = '20' then 1 end) = 0
```

Note: use standard ANSI joins.

Cheers!!